# Can I travel to the UK with a sealed and expunged record?

Tags: uk, international-travel, us-citizens

Can a person travel to the UK and has a sealed & expunged record in which the charges were misdemeanors. Would this preclude me from being able to obtain entry into the UK?

Comment: Do you require a visa? If you do, then answer the questions truthfully, giving no more information than is requested.

Comment: No I am American citizen.

Comment: Please visit the UK gov website [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). I just tried that and it says (for what you've said) *"You may want to apply for a Standard Visitor visa if you have a criminal record or you’ve previously been refused entry into the UK."* Immigration procedures are generally exempt from recognising expungement terms of other countries, and UK/USA share information.

Comment: You said the *charges* ... did you mean *convictions*?

Comment: Yes sorry i was charged and released. I was placed on probation as well in a group home that was all. I served it and had it sealed and expunged.

Comment: Of you were placed on probation then you were **convicted** (found guilty of a crime). Peaple found to be innocent are not placed on probation.